# ¿Como puedo hacer un filtro de busqueda por fechas en angular 6?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular6

me gustaría saber como logro hacer un filtro de búsqueda por fecha de contratación de una tabla empleados teniendo una fecha de inicio y una fecha de fin.
 este es mi html

```
<div style="justify-content:center">
  <mat-card style="  max-width: 900px;  ">
    <div class="example-container">
      <mat-card-title> Resporte buscando información de empleados por fecha de contratación</mat-card-title>
      <mat-form-field>
          <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Seleccione una fecha desde">
          <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
          <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div><br>
    <div class="example-container">
        <mat-form-field>
            <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker2" placeholder="Seleccione una fecha hasta">
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker2"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker #picker2></mat-datepicker>
          </mat-form-field>
      </div>
    <button mat-raised-button>Buscar</button> <br>
  </mat-card>
</div><br>
```

Agradeceria inmensamente la ayuda!.

Comment: En ese código no hay ninguna tabla. Deberías además añadir el código del componente, para saber cómo guardas los datos. ¿Quieres filtrar un array que ya tiene los datos?

Answer (score 0):

Para comparar fechas, te recomiendo que trabajes siempre en su formato en milisegundos.

Así, por ejemplo, obteniendo el objeto de tipo Date de "picker" y "picker2" mediante ngModel:

HTML

```
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Seleccione una fecha desde" [(ngModel)] = "pickerDate">

<input matInput [matDatepicker]="picke2r" placeholder="Seleccione una fecha hasta" [(ngModel)] = "pickerDate2">)
```

Cuando pulses el botón de buscar, por tanto, basta con convertir los dates en millisegundos y buscar todas aquellas fechas entre ambas.

TypeScript

```
onSearch() {
   fechasFiltradas = this.myDates
          .filter((date: Date) => pickerDate.getTime() < date.getTime() < pickerDate2.getTime());
}
```

Un saludo!